# Why don't my Fujifilm X-A20 autofocus after putting back on original lens?

Tags: lens, autofocus, digital, fujifilm

I have a Fujifilm X-A20, but I removed its original lens around 4 years ago and have been using a meike lens I bought at the same time. Today I decided to put back the original lens to use it but I have encountered problems. If the "Shoot without lens" option is off, it wont take a picture. If it is on, it will take a picture but won't autofocus so the viewfinder is blurry. I can't seem to adjust the aperture also. And the lens wont zoom in and out. Please help me. I'm not gadget savvy. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it is mounted correctly? You could try to give the [contacts a clean](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+clean+camera+lens+contacts). Does the Meike lens continue to work correctly when put on the camera again now?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted, it appears you have a Fujifilm X-A20 camera and the XC 15-45 mm F3.5-5.6 OIS PZ power zoom kit lens. You clearly have a communication fault between your camera and the lens.

You need to inspect and/or clean the electrical communication contacts on both the camera and the lens. If the contacts are okay, you will need to try another lens or camera to identify which of the two is faulty, and then have it repaired.

[image]